# Convexity of the boundary of a geodesically convex submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Before I ask my question, let me set up a few definitions. Suppose $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold. Then:

- a subset $K \subset M$ is said to be geodesically convex if for any pair of points $p,q \in K$, there exists a geodesic segment $[p,q]$ of $(M,g)$ such that $[p,q] \subset K$.
- an oriented hypersurface $H\subset M$ with unit normal $\nu$ is said to be convex if its *shape operator* $S$, defined by $SX = \left(\nabla_{X}\nu\right)^{\top}$ (that is, it is the orthogonal projection onto $TH$ of $\nabla_X \nu$) is positive semi-definite with respect to $g|_H$, that is
  $$
  \forall X \in \mathfrak{X}(H), g\left(SX,X\right) \geqslant 0.
  $$

In [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601503), it is said (page 6, at the beginning of the proof of Theorem 4) that "it is well known that $K$ geodesically convex implies that $Y = \partial K$ is convex" (with respect to the **outward** unit normal). I am OK with this, it seems natural and visually clear. But I can't find any reference of that fact. I guess it's a very basic proof but I somehow cannot manage to show it. I think I'm missing the key argument.

It is well known that if $X$ and $Y$ are tangent to $\partial K$, then
$
g\left(SX,Y\right) = -g\left(\nabla_XY,\nu\right)
$,
and the claimed result can be rephrased as: If $K$ is geodesically convex, then:
$
\forall X \in \mathfrak{X}(\partial K),~ g\left(\nabla_X X, \nu \right) \leqslant 0.
$

Of course, this last formulation suggests that there is something to do with the equation of geodesics or something similar. However, I can't manage to conclude any further and it is a bit frustrating. I would be very grateful if anyone could help me conclude.